# What is the benefit of Shell Sort versus Insertion/Bubble Sort?

Tags: sorting

My professor gave me the following definition of Shell Sort. I've included the Bubble and Insertion Sort algorithms as well.

What is the advantage of using Shell Sort vs just a regular Insertion Sort or Bubble Sort with `gap=1`? Eventually, the Shell Sort boils down to that anyway, right?

I'm not asking you to do my homework. I'm legitimately confused and want to understand what's going on.

Also, I've already visited Wikipedia and seen the Time Complexity table and I already know what they say. I'm looking for the *why*, not the *what*.

```
def shell(a, n):
    gap = n / 2

    while gap >= 1:
            insertion(a, n, gap) # or bubble
            gap /= 2

def bubble(a, n, gap=1):
    for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n-i-gap):
                    if a[j] > a[j+gap]:
                            swap(a, j, j+1)

def insertion(a, n, gap=1):
    for i in range(1,n):
            x = a[i]
            j = i-gap

            while j>=0 and  a[j]>x:
                    a[j+gap] = a[j]
                    j-=gap

            a[j+gap]=x
```

Comment: You may find [Combsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort) interesting. It seems like not many people know if it, which is a shame.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shell sort allows swapping of indexes that are far apart, where bubble sort only swaps items that are adjacent.

The wikipedia entries on

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

cover the differences.

Edit:

Imagine that you've got a bunch of cards in your hand and the cards are almost in order, except the first and last are swapped. bubble sort would be a pain to do, because there'd be about 2n swaps, insertion sort would be better with n swaps, but shell sort could do it in 1. (the number of swaps varies based on algorithm implementation, this is just an example)

Comment: Yes, I know that. I want to know why using multiple gaps greater than one is *better* than using gap=1.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but wouldn't you have to have prior knowledge of the order of the list to make good use of the Shell sort? What if the list is just random, wouldn't it be a big waste of time to go through the list, gap/=2 each time?

Comment: Oh, bubblesort and insertion sort aren't meant to be used as general sort algorithms (they have their advantages, but those are rare), they're taught to help you understand sort algorithms. If you were to understand how sorting works via quicksort or mergesort as a first attempt, you'd probably go crazy. They're also much harder to implement correctly. Bubblesort is so simple to write, and to understand that it's sorting, but is quite inefficient.

Comment: As you can see, the other posters are posting basically that same information, that shell sort is much better. Knowing the big oh runtimes for these algorithms is standard fare for all CS students everywhere.

Answer (score 7):

The logic of shell sort is to sort entries that are further away first. Given a partially sorted list you can in theory sort a lot faster than O(n^2). Also given a large unsorted array the probability that your final sorted position being far from your current position is high. So logically it makes sense to use a larger gap. But the main point of shell sorts is not really its performance, instead it is the simplicity of the algorithm and the low usage of stack memory.

Given that on average it does better than O(n^2) (depends of the gap sequence), small code sizes and stack usages it is very popular in embedded applications where memory constraints are a factor.

Comment: Very good answer; it complements the accepted answer quite nicely, as it addresses situations where Shell Sort may be preferred over faster algorithms such as quicksort.

Answer (score -8):

The diference is the efficiency.

Insertion Sort and Bubble sort are both O(n^2), meanwhile Shell Sort is O(n log n).

That means if you have a collection that has 100 elements, the amount of operations with Bubble and Insert sort are K * 100^2 = K *  10000 operations, where K depends of others factors, but is mostly constant.

Using the Shell Sort, the operations needed will be Q * 100 * Log 100 = Q * 100 * 2 = Q * 2000 operations, where Q depends on others factors and is mostly constant.

Comment: If Shell Sort is O(n log n), then I'd love to see a reference.

Comment: The asymptotic complexity of Shell sort, as well as the best sequence of increments, and the 
 asymptotic average-care complexity are open problems.